# How should I render YAML arrays neatly with cookiecutter?

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2, templating-engine, cookiecutter

I have a cookiecutter template that I want to render a YAML file based on some options.

As a simple example, suppose a rendered YAML file could look like this:

```
supported_databases:
  - mysql
  - postgres
```

And my cookiecutter JSON looked like this:

```
{
  "mysql": ["yes", "no"],
  "postgres": ["yes", "no"]
}
```

My YAML file is going to be horribly peppered with `if`s to support all 4 valid combinations:

```
{%- if cookiecutter.mysql == 'yes' or cookiecutter.postgres == 'yes' %}
supported_databases:
{%- if cookiecutter.mysql == 'yes' %}
  - mysql
{%- endif %}
{%- if cookiecutter.mysql == 'yes' %}
  - postgres
{%- endif %}
{%- endif %}
```

The outer `if` is required to prevent invalid YAML being rendered in the case when both options are 'no'.

Is there a neater way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of YAML's flow style:

```
supported_databases: [
  {% for db_type in ['mysql', 'postgres'] %}
    {% if cookiecutter[db_type] == 'yes' %}{{ db_type }},{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  ]
```

If both options are `no`, this renders:

```
supported_databases: [
  ]
```

Which is valid YAML representing an empty sequence as value for `supported_databases`.

With both options present, you get

```
supported_databases: [
    mysql,
    postgres,
  ]
```

Which is also valid YAML since unlike JSON, YAML allows a trailing comma in sequences. This YAML is semantically equivalent to the YAML you show in the question.

*Caution: Code untested.*